# How are blank nodes used in the context of understanding RDF triple statements?

Tags: rdf, rdfs, blank-nodes

I understand that a `named node` in RDF is a node that has a name (i.e. can be identified by an IRI), and that a `blank node` is a node that is not named (i.e. not described via an IRI).

Is it correct to say that a node represents a resource in RDF? In this case, both named and blank nodes would be considered resources.

Looking at an RDF schema I see a number of XML tags that seem to represent nodes (both blank and named). For example:

```
<rdf:Description rdf:about="http://.../SomeObject">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Class"/>
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="http://.../OtherClass"/>
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:nodeID="node1e2d5tndrx143"/>
</rdf:Description>
```

and

```
<rdf:Description rdf:nodeID="node1e2d5tndrx60">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#Datatype"/>
    <owl:oneOf rdf:nodeID="node1e2d5tndrx61"/>
</rdf:Description>
```

(and because this node references another blank node)

```
<rdf:Description rdf:nodeID="node1e2d5tndrx61">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#List"/>
    <rdf:first>1</rdf:first>
    <rdf:rest rdf:nodeID="node1e2d5tndrx62"/>
</rdf:Description>
```

It would seem to me that the resources available at this particular API endpoint include these three nodes, one of which is named `http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#float` and two of which are blank (`node1e2d5tndrx60`, `node1e2d5tndrx61`)

This link - https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-esw-thes/2004Nov/0061.html - seemingly an old w3.org on the subject of `rdf:about` vs `rdf:ID` vs `rdf:nodeID` mentions that blank nodes are indicated via the `rdf:nodeID` attribute.

If both these nodes are 'resources' at this particular API endpoint (I assume they are - please let me know if that is incorrect), so far as I know I could never query for a blank node directly, but that in this particular RDF document the blank nodes are being used to constrain what objects are allowed (via the `rdf:range` property) for a triple that specifies the `hasObjectClass` property/predicate:

```
<rdf:Description rdf:about="http://.../hasSomeObjectClass">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#DatatypeProperty"/>
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#FunctionalProperty"/>
    <rdfs:label>Some Object Class</rdfs:label>
    <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="http://..../SomeObject"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:nodeID="node1e2d5tndrx60"/>
</rdf:Description>
```

My understanding is that triples using the :hasSomeObjectClass predicate (`<subj> <pred> <obj>`) will:

1. Include/can only include subjects that are of `rdf:type` "SomeObject"
2. Include/can only include objects that are 'subtyped' of the blank node `node1e2d5tndrx60`

Lastly, in blank node `node1e2d5tndrx60` I see that there is an `owl` constraint - any allowable object can be considered as part of a list. Presumably a list of objects that share a particular class?

**Question**

Looking at the domain property of the `hasSomeObjectClass` resource, I am able to find:

1. A node that represents the `SomeObject` class
2. Many nodes that have the `rdfs:subClassOf` property and that reference `SomeObject` as the resource

So in terms of how a triple specification is resolved in which the predicate specifies a domain of this type, I understand conceptually how that can be enforced/resolved.

However I can't see a link between the blank node and how the range constraint could be enforced/resolved. **Is it easy to explain on a conceptual level how blank nodes are used in terms of resolving specified triples?**

I'm very, very new to the world of Linked Data. Please let me know how this question could be improved on!

Comment: Consider blank nodes as existential variables. Also, blank nodes are used in RDF lists and in RDF serialisations if complex OWL axioms.

Comment: what are 'existential variables'?

Comment: existential variables are variables in a first order logic formula that are existentially quantified with the symbol ∃, e.g., in the FOL formula ∃x P(x), the variable x is an existential variable. They indicate the existence of a thing. Similarly, in an RDF graph, a blank node indicates the existence of a thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Blank nodes identifiers are local identifiers, not IRIs. Blank nodes are disjoint with IRIs and literals [as defined](https://www.w3.org/TR/rdf11-concepts/#section-blank-nodes) in the RDF specification.

A few popular application of blank nodes are:

1. Describing multi-component structures such as lists, or grouping of triples, such as the case when an object of a triple being address, which is identified not with an IRI but with a set of triples describing it.

```
locn:address [
       rdf:type locn:Address ;
       locn:addressArea "Amsterdam"@en ;
       locn:fullAddress "Oudekerksplein 23"@en ;
       locn:postCode "1012 GX" .
     ] .
```

This is the most popular way of denoting blank nodes, but they can also be revealed:

```
ex:AdddressDeOudeKerk locn:address _:b1 .
_:b1 rdf:type locn:Address .
_:b1 locn:addressArea "Amsterdam"@en .
_:b1 locn:fullAddress "Oudekerksplein 23"@en .
_:b1 locn:postCode "1012 GX" .
```

2. Making statements about statements

   2.1. With reification

   2.2. Alternative approaches, for example, the one used in Wikidata.

For example, in this query

```
SELECT ?president ?presidentLabel ?image ?start
WHERE {
    ?president  wdt:P31 wd:Q5 ;      
         p:P39 [ ps:P39 wd:Q11696;
                 pq:P580 ?start ];
         wdt:P18 ?image .

   SERVICE wikibase:label {
           bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" .
   }

 }
```

`p:P39` is a property for the *statement* "position held", while `ps:P39` is to the *value* "position held" The blank not is such a statement, which is the value (the object) of the triple pattern `?president p:P39 ?statement` for which `?statement ps:P39 wd:Q11696` and `?statement pq:P580 ?start` and to ask fora particular characteristic of the statement,in this case "start time" (with qualifier `pq:P580`)

3. Anonymous classes in OWL
   Example:

```
:Vegetarian rdf:type owl:Class ;
        owl:equivalentClass [ rdf:type owl:Restriction ;
                              owl:onProperty :eats ;
                              owl:allValuesFrom :Vegetable
                            ] .
```

4. Shapes in SHACL
   Example:

```
:Contract
  rdf:type sh:NodeShape ;
  sh:property [
      rdf:type sh:PropertyShape ;
      sh:path :hasParty ;
      sh:minCount 2 ;
      sh:name "has party" ;
    ] ;
  sh:targetSubjectsOf :hasParty ;
.
```

Comment: "Blank nodes are local identifiers" -> be carefully, the spec does not say this. It says "Blank nodes *identifiers* are local identifiers". Blank nodes themselves are not identifiers at all.

Comment: Indeed. Corrected. Thanks.